# gameタブにすると虹色のマークが出て終了してしまいます。どうすればよいでしょうか。

Tags: macos, unity3d

お世話になっています。Unityを始めたばかりなのですが、作ったシーンを確認しようとgameタブにすると強制終了してしまいます。知り合いに一度聞いたところ、Unity内でパフォーマンスのクオリティを設定する場所があって、その設定を下げれば正常に動作するという風に教えていただいたのですが、その設定がどのようなものだったか忘れてしまいました。
Macbook proでunity5.5を使用しています。
まだ右も左もわからずわかりづらい内容になってしまいますが、どなたかそうしたコマンドをご存知ないでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

『Unity - マニュアル: Quality Settings (画質設定)』
https://docs.unity3d.com/jp/540/Manual/class-QualitySettings.html

ここに画質を設定する方法が記述されています。
ここで選択された設定(画質)がエディタ側でも反映されたはずです。

「unity クオリティ 設定」でググれば一番上に出てきます。

まずは知りたい項目でググってみましょう。